TypeORM Entity Not Auto-Populating createdAt and updatedAt Fields on Insert Body:
I recently migrated an Express.js project from Sequelize ORM to TypeORM. In Sequelize, the createdAt and updatedAt fields were automatically managed without any issues. However, after switching to TypeORM, I encountered an error when inserting records into a table that was previously working fine with Sequelize.
The error message is as follows:

error: null value in column "createdAt" of relation "verification" violates not-null constraint

Below is the Sequilize model(Old):
Verification.init(
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            },

            verification_data: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: false
            },
            verification_type: {
                type: DataTypes.ENUM('MOBILE', 'EMAIL'),
                allowNull: false
            },
            verification_code: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: false
            },
            verification_status: {
                type: DataTypes.ENUM('PENDING', 'VERIFIED'),
                defaultValue: 'PENDING',
                allowNull: false
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: true,
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            },
            deletedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            },

        }
        , {
            sequelize,
            paranoid: true,
            modelName: 'Verification',
            tableName: 'verification',
        });

Below is the TypeORM entity :
@Entity('verification')
export class Verification {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    verification_data: string;

    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: VerificationType,
        enumName: 'enum_verification_verification_type'
    })
    verification_type: VerificationType;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    verification_code: string;

    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: VerificationStatus,
        default: VerificationStatus.PENDING,
        enumName: 'enum_verification_verification_status'
    })
    verification_status: VerificationStatus;

    @CreateDateColumn({type: "timestamp with time zone"})
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({type: "timestamp with time zone"})
    updatedAt: Date;

    @DeleteDateColumn({type: "timestamp with time zone"})
    deletedAt: Date;
}


And here is the relevant SQL for the table, as managed in PgAdmin:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.verification
(
    ...
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    ...
)

In Sequelize, I did not need to explicitly set createdAt and updatedAt - it was handled automatically. I expected TypeORM's @CreateDateColumn and @UpdateDateColumn decorators to work similarly, but they seem not to be populating these fields upon insertion.
Adding default values to createdAt and updatedAt fields directly in the database schema works as a temporary fix, but I was under the impression that TypeORM should handle these automatically.
The project is already in production, so enabling synchronize: true in TypeORM to auto-generate columns is not an option.
How can I resolve this issue to have TypeORM automatically manage createdAt and updatedAt fields without manual intervention or altering the production database schema?
